# How is "Rather than" used in a sentence and what verb is used after it?

Tags: grammar, phrases, prepositions, tenses, conjunctions

I have searched all over the internet for this question for two days and used many robots to check my examples using this phrase.
It is simple to use for adjectives and adverbs and nouns so I don't want them being explained.
What is confusing are verbs.
What kind of verbs are used after "Rather than"?
There are three options. 1- Parallel structure. 2-Gerund. 3-Infinitive

According to a website, these sentences are incorrect yet they follow the parallel structure and that confuses me:

1- He asked first rather than went in. [Wrong] (“go in” is correct while parallel of “asked” is “went”)

2- We took a taxi, rather than got lost on foot. [Wrong] (“get lost” is correct while parallel of “took” is “got”)

3- I asked her about her problems rather than tell her what to do. [Wrong] (contrary to example 1 & 2, “told” is correct)

4- He walked home rather than drove to work. [correct] (it is correct but it is contrary to example 1 & 2)

5- They would have gone to the city rather than stayed here. [Wrong](“stay” is correct while parallel of “gone” is “stayed”)

6- They would have gone to the city rather than staying here. [Wrong] (“stay” is correct)

7- He asked first, rather than going in. [correct] (contrary to example 6, “ing” here is correct)

8- He will try to have them changed rather than disobeyed them. [Wrong] (“disobey” is correct while parallel of “changed” is “disobeyed”)

Comment: As far as I can see the right/wrong comments in your examples are (i) completely random or (ii) refer to errors that are not associated with "rather than"; neither do the comments take into account any context. "Rather than" introduces an alternative to the idea expressed in the preceding or following clause or phrase. The verb (where there is a verb) may be in any form.

Comment: I am afraid that you are asking too much in one question. Correcting and explaining eight examples is excessive.

Comment: No, you need to learn those for yourself, or ask your teacher. Nobody else knows what "correct" means to **you**. And if you do need to learn why; otherwise you'll hafta be asking us to do your homework every week.

Comment: Have you searched this site for “rather?” There’s quite a bit.

Comment: Related: [1](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/22534), [2](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/138800), [3](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/238758), [4](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/281776), [5](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/439786).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be trying to over-analyze this. The [Cambridge Dictionary teaches us:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/rather)

> **Rather than: alternatives and preferences**
>
> We use rather than to give more importance to one thing when two alternatives or preferences are being compared:
>
> *He wanted to be an actor rather than a comedian.*
>
> *Can we come over on Saturday rather than Friday?*
>
> *Rather than* usually occurs between two things which are being compared. However, we can also use it at the beginning of a sentence. When we use rather than with a verb, we use the base form or (less commonly) the -ing form of a verb:
>
> *Rather than pay the taxi fare, he walked home.* (or Rather than paying the taxi fare, he walked home.)
>
> Not: Rather than to pay …

I'm a native English speaker in the western United States. Here's your list followed by how I would formally say each phrase and how I could expect to hear the phrase colloquially.

> He asked first rather than went in. [Wrong] (“go in” is correct while parallel of “asked” is “went”)
>
> He asked first, rather than going in. [correct] (contrary to example 6, “ing” here is correct)

- Formally, "He asked first rather than going in unannounced."
- Colloquially, "He asked first rather than going in."

> We took a taxi, rather than got lost on foot. [Wrong] (“get lost” is correct while parallel of “took” is “got”)

*Formally, "We took a taxi rather than getting lost on foot."
*Colloquially, "We took a taxi rather than get lost on foot."

> I asked her about her problems rather than tell her what to do. [Wrong] (contrary to example 1 & 2, “told” is correct)

*Formally, "I asked her about her problems rather than telling her what to do."
*Colloquially, "I asked her about her problems rather than tell her what to do."

> He walked home rather than drove to work. [correct] (it is correct but it is contrary to example 1 & 2)

- Formally, "He walked home rather than driving to work."
- Colloquially, "He walked home rather than driving to work."

> They would have gone to the city rather than stayed here. [Wrong](“stay” is correct while parallel of “gone” is “stayed”)
>
> They would have gone to the city rather than staying here. [Wrong] (“stay” is correct)

These two examples bring an issue of complexity to the discussion. You have a double-condition. The "rather than" identifies an alternative that would have been taken had a different decision been made, but that decision also didn't occur the way the "rather than" expected. The examples appear incomplete to me. They need the justification for the double-condition to be explained. For example:

- "They would have gone to the city rather than stay here, but the football game is on TV and they want to watch it."

> He will try to have them changed rather than disobeyed them. [Wrong] (“disobey” is correct while parallel of “changed” is “disobeyed”)

- Formally, "He will try to have the law changed rather than disobey it."
- Colloquially, "Rather than disobey the law, he will try to have it changed."

Comment: Possibly the city one should be "They would rather have gone to the city than stay here."

Comment: @Showsni That's what someone else said too. I think you are right. thank you very much JBH for the time you put into writing all this and thank you too Showsni.

Comment: I question your formal-vs-colloquial distinction in these. What governs your choices in these?  I ask because they don't align always with my own expectations. It's not like the gerund is "more formal" than the bare infinitive. I question that these would be inappropriate anywhere.

Comment: @tchrist What governs my choices is how people in my area say and how they react to more formal speech or how they present themselves using written language. I'm very involved in my community and review a great deal of written material. If you prefer, I may have used as a better choice, "written language" vs "spoken language."

Answer (score 0):

There are distinct meanings associated with "rather than"  depending on whether a finite or nonfinite form is used.

- 1- Parallel structure.: *The action is similar to the action in the main clause,  and the speaker is saying that this is not quite what he did (does) or  what was (is) done. Also, when the   action is usual the finite form shows that it is not as often chosen.*
- 2-Gerund. 3-Infinitive: *The action  has not been  performed, it is different,  and the speaker is saying that he chose (chooses) not to carry  it out at all, or that it has not been  chosen as a possibility.*

(*Supposing  that the bracketed word is the conclusion of the robots*)

1- He asked first rather than went in. [Wrong] (“go in” is correct while parallel of “asked” is “went”)

*Robot correct: no similarity between  "asking" and "going in".*

2- We took a taxi, rather than got lost on foot. [Wrong] (“get lost” is correct while parallel of “took” is “got”)

*Robot correct: no similarity between  "taking a taxi" and "getting lost".*

3- I asked her about her problems rather than tell her what to do. [Wrong] (contrary to example 1 & 2, “told” is correct)

*Robot not correct: no similarity between  "asking" and "telling what to do"*

4- He walked home rather than drove to work. [correct] (it is correct but it is contrary to example 1 & 2)

*Robot not correct: no similarity between  "walking home" and "driving to work"*

He walked home rather than drive/driving to work.

ex.: ([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/From_Azaleas_to_Zydeco/0AttAwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22rather+than+driving+to%22&pg=PA82&printsec=frontcoverhttps://www.google.fr/books/edition/From_Azaleas_to_Zydeco/0AttAwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22rather+than+driving+to%22&pg=PA82&printsec=frontcover)) Rather than driving to races, he gets on a private jet early on race Sundays to fly to the race.

([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/The_Aging_Intellect/2F6RAgAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22rather+than+driving+to%22&pg=PT195&printsec=frontcover)) When Henry replayed his mistake of waiting for his wife to call him well beyond the time her plane was scheduled to arrive rather than driving to the terminal to see if she was there, he had no trouble recognizing his error and will not

ex.: He  jogged  rather than  walked  home  everyday after work.

5- They would have gone to the city rather than stayed here. [Wrong](“stay” is correct while parallel of “gone” is “stayed”)

*Robot correct: no similarity between  "going to the city" and "staying somewhere".*

6- They would have gone to the city rather than staying here. [Wrong] (“stay” is correct)

*Robot not correct: no similarity between  "going" and "staying"*

7- He asked first, rather than going in. [correct] (contrary to example 6, “ing” here is correct)

*Robot correct: no similarity between  "asking" and "going in".*

*Robot correct: no similarity between  "going to the city" and "staying somewhere".*

8- He will try to have them changed rather than disobeyed them. [Wrong] (“disobey” is correct while parallel of “changed” is “disobeyed”)

*Robot correct: no similarity between  "try to have sth changed" and "disobeying".*

Comment: Thank you, I just don't understand what you mean by similarity. Your example about jogging and walking manifests the similarity of the two words but I have an example here: [ref](https://www.economist.com/taxonomy/term/35/0)  "They think that Greece's debt crisis has been postponed rather than solved." The similarity is not obvious, yet it is parallel.

Comment: @Piran  It seems that postponement could   be considered as some temporary solution,  wouldn't  you say?

Comment: I guess so. Thank you again for the time you put into writing it.